# Microsoft Analysis Services Resources

Tags: ssas

Can anyone recommend a good primer on Analysis Services?

Website or book recommendations appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chapters on Analysis Services of Programming Microsoft SQL Server 2008 by Lobel-Brust-Forte [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-Server-2008-PRO-Developer/dp/0735625999/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1286428641&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625999) were really useful when I was starting on the subject, it's readable, simple, a good starting point.